# "cudaGetDevice() failed" despite following instructions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have gone through all the [steps necessary to get a software called DeepLabCut running](https://github.com/AlexEMG/DeepLabCut/blob/master/docs/installation.md#step-2-easy-install-for-windows-macos-ubuntu-please-use-our-supplied-anaconda-environments) and in the end, I get the following error

`InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version`

BUT
My CUDA version is 9.0

```
C:\Users\xxx>nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:32_Central_Daylight_Time_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176
```

And my driver version is the one that says it should be compatible.

`NVIDIA Driver version 385.54`

If I run

`sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))`

I get

```
2020-03-03 17:12:44.099395: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2020-03-03 17:12:44.107794: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Quadro P400 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.2525
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0
2020-03-03 17:12:44.112565: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2020-03-03 17:12:44.121275: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-dad9f5fa93d0> in <module>
----> 1 sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\DLC-GPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, target, graph, config)
   1568
   1569     """
-> 1570     super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
   1571     # NOTE(mrry): Create these on first `__enter__` to avoid a reference cycle.
   1572     self._default_graph_context_manager = None

C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\DLC-GPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, target, graph, config)
    691     try:
    692       # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 693       self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSessionRef(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
    694       # pylint: enable=protected-access
    695     finally:

InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

Please let me know what further information I can provide

Thank you!

**More information**

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.12.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

In [2]: import tensorflow as tf

In [3]: print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
2020-03-03 19:02:07.292400: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-03-03 19:02:07.443544: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Quadro P400 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.2525
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0
2020-03-03 19:02:07.448224: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2020-03-03 19:02:07.453367: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
Num GPUs Available:  1

In [4]: sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
2020-03-03 19:02:52.859131: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2020-03-03 19:02:52.865056: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Quadro P400 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.2525
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0
2020-03-03 19:02:52.869160: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2020-03-03 19:02:52.873013: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-dad9f5fa93d0> in <module>
----> 1 sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\DLC-GPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, target, graph, config)
   1568
   1569     """
-> 1570     super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
   1571     # NOTE(mrry): Create these on first `__enter__` to avoid a reference cycle.
   1572     self._default_graph_context_manager = None

C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\DLC-GPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, target, graph, config)
    691     try:
    692       # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 693       self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSessionRef(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
    694       # pylint: enable=protected-access
    695     finally:

InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

Comment: Just update your driver -- anaconda is using an internal CUDA installation which is not compatible with your driver version

Comment: The issue with this solution @talonmies is that not every nvidia driver is compatible with every CUDA installation. I was made sure that this combination was tested and working.

Comment: Anaconda uses its own CUDA version, not whatever else you installed yourself. Install the latest driver. It supports all CUDA versions your GPU does

Comment: It was an issue with the tensorflow version, or the interaction between the program and all the environment variables. With python 3.6 and tensorflow 1.8 the problem was solved.

Comment: "GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check" -- as I have said several times, the problem was that the tensorflow version you had was statically linked against a newer version of CUDA than your driver supported. The version of CUDA you had installed was irrelevant. Simply updating your driver would have fixed this

Comment: I understand what you mean, talonmies, but being this project for a scientific endeavour, I need to do things in ways are replicable with (mostly) the exact conditions (in this case the running environment of the software). The software documentation required specific versions of drivers. If this were just the need for make it run without errors, I would follow your advice. You were the only one who replied to this and I truly appreciate it! If the software gets updated, I will probably update the driver and give it a go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the tensorflow version, or the interaction between the program and all the environment variables. With python 3.6 and tensorflow 1.8 the problem was solved. 
What I did was to edit the environment file to specify those versions and it worked. I know this is not a definite answer, but it might help getting it to work in some other situations and a starting point to finding the real issue. 
These were the environment variables:

```
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - pip
  - tensorflow-gpu==1.8
  - cudnn=7
  - wxpython
  - jupyter
  - nb_conda
  - Shapely
  - pip:
    - deeplabcut
```